# Getting xy data from matplotlib fig object

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to retrieve XY data from a fig object with 2 subplots.

Here is the way I made the fig object:

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(1,2)
axarr[0].imshow(labels_map,vmax=28)
axarr[1].imshow(Y_predictions,vmax=28)
np.save('fig.npy', f)
```

I can't remake the fig objects, because I no longer have access to the machine.

from a previous stackoverflow post:

```
fig = numpy.load("fig.npy").item()
ax = fig.gca()
xy_data = ax.get_lines()
print(xy_data[0])
```

printing fails: "list index out of range"

I need to get the 2d array for both the subplots in order to make a confusion matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no line(s) in your plots; but images. Hence,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f, axarr = plt.subplots(1,2)
axarr[0].imshow(np.random.randint(0,28, (10,10)),vmax=28)
np.save('fig.npy', f)
plt.close()

fig = np.load("fig.npy").item()
data = fig.axes[0].images[0].get_array()
print(data)
```

Comment: Also now I feel stupid for not finding it in the documentation myself. A true RTFM moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
xy_data = ax.get_lines()[0].get_data()
print (xy_data)
```

Comment: The result is: <a list of 0 Line2D objects>

Comment: @Paku : sorry, check the edit. I was writing from phone

Comment: xy_data = ax.get_lines()[0].get_data()
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: xy_data = ax.get_lines().get_data()
AttributeError: 'silent_list' object has no attribute 'get_data'

Comment: @Paku What do you get when you do `len(ax.get_lines())`

Comment: My subplots did not have lines, but images : () I should have read the axes documentation more.